# I want to add export and import to my application. My database is hive flutter. How?

Tags: flutter, import, hive, export, flutter-hive

I want to add export and import database to my application. My database is hive flutter. I tried several methods but it didn't work

```
ElevatedButton(onPressed: () async{

  final String? pathHive=Hive.box<Cart>(cartBoxName).path;
  Directory dir=Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
  await File(pathHive!).copy('$dir/backup.hive');
}
```

it didn't work

Answer (score -1):

you can use those methods in order to import/export a backup file for your `Hive` box in your flutter app:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

Future<void> backupHiveBox<T>(String boxName, String backupPath) async {
  final box = await Hive.openBox<T>(boxName);
  final boxPath = box.path;
  await box.close();

  try {
    File(boxPath).copy(backupPath);
  } finally {
    await Hive.openBox<T>(boxName);
  }
}

Future<void> restoreHiveBox<T>(String boxName, String backupPath) async {
  final box = await Hive.openBox<T>(boxName);
  final boxPath = box.path;
  await box.close();

  try {
    File(backupPath).copy(boxPath);
  } finally {
    await Hive.openBox<T>(boxName);
  }
}
```

The concept over it, is that open the `Hive` box first (if it's already open then you can just get its instance ), Then, using `dart:io` we can export/import a `File` with the path of the `Hive` Box that we got with `box.path`.

And make sure that the box should be closed when you make the copying operation into/from a file, after that you can open it again.